# Trying to make a respawn trigger, but any rigid body (or collider probably) keeps triggering it. Any ideas?

Tags: unity, c#, rigidbody

I'm trying to make it so that if any object passes through with the matching tag it will reload the level. However, any rigid body (or collider) is setting it off which is not the desired behavior.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DamageAuroa : MonoBehaviour {

    public int PHP; //PHP = Player Health from PlayerHealth.cs script.
    public int Damage; //Amount of damage.
    public string Level;

    void Start()
    {
        PHP = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().PlayerHP;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Player")
            PHP = PHP - Damage;

        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Ball")
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
            Application.LoadLevel(Level);

        if (PHP <= 0)
            Application.LoadLevel(Level);

    }

}
```

Any idea why this happens? Or is it something wrong with Unity? Probably just an end user issue.

Comment: Have you marked the collider as trigger?

Comment: Yes, but that's not the issue really. The issue being that the trigger activates with any rigid body/collider.

Comment: Try creating layers for different objects.Then you can go to Edit->Project Settings->Physics and choose which layer collides with the layer of this object. Only objects on the layers which are allowed to collide will trigger. Rest will pass through it like it doesn't exist.

Comment: BTW, is it 2D or 3D?

Comment: It's 3D, and I don't really see why the layer should matter. It should just be activating when a collider with the marked tag enters it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Ball")
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
            Application.LoadLevel(Level);
```

You're missing parenthesis there. Application.LoadLevel isn't affected by the `if` condition, so it's firing every time.

Turn it to this:

```
if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Ball")
     {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
            Application.LoadLevel(Level);
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you. Where do I put the parenthesis so that when it matches "Ball" than it restarts the level, or how would I set that up?

Comment: @MEOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW i have edited the answer. Solution is there now.

Comment: Damned brackets screwing me up again. Sheesh. Thank you.